# "Bring noch eine/einen Stern mit"

Tags: gender, colloquial

Stern ist männlich: "der Stern", aber Zeitschrift ist weiblich: "die Zeitschrift". Wenn ich meine Freundin frage die Zeitschrift "Stern" mit zu bringen, was soll ich denn fragen:

> Bring noch eine Stern mit.

oder

> Bring noch einen Stern mit.

Answer (score 11):

Es gibt einige Arten von Objekten, bei denen sich das Genus eines
Eigennamens fast immer nach der Kategorie richtet, zu der das Objekt
gehört, und nicht nach der Bedeutung des Namens. Ein bekanntes
Beispiel sind Autonamen, die fast immer maskulin sind (z.B. "der Polo",
obwohl "Polo" als Sportart Neutrum ist; "der Wartburg", obwohl "Burg"
feminin ist).

Für Zeitungen und Zeitschriften gilt das aber *nicht*. Hier richtet
sich das Genus in der Regel nach der Bedeutung des Namens. Es
heißt also "der Spiegel", "der Stern", "das Neue Deutschland",
"der Mannheimer Morgen", "der Guardian" und "der Figaro".
(Für Zeitungen gilt diese Regel fast durchgehend (außer "*die* Bild"),
bei Illustrierten sind die Ausnahmen etwas häufiger, z.B. "*die* Capital", "*die* TV Spielfilm").

Comment: Die Bild ist streng genommen keine Ausnahme, weil sie ja eigentlich tatsächlich früher offiziell die '[Bildzeitung](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bild_(Zeitung))' hieß. Heute nur noch in der Kurzform gebräuchlich.

Answer (score 9):

> Bringe mir noch einen Stern mit.

Die Zeitschrift heißt `Stern`, der wie du schon sagst männlich ist. Also muss auch, wenn Stern alleine steht, der entsprechende Artikel genannt werden. Alternativ kannst du auch sagen:

> Bringe mir noch den Stern mit.

`die` käme zur Anwendung, wenn du sagen würdest:

> Bringe mir noch eine Stern-Zeitschrift mit.

Comment: "eine Stern-Zeitschrift" wäre allerdings sehr unidiomatisch.

Comment: Ist "bringe" besser als "bring"?

Comment: Ist der Stern nicht ein Magazin?

Comment: @stevenvh "bring" ist umgangssprachlich und müsste korrekt "bring'" geschrieben werden, da der korrekte imperativ "bringe" heißt.

Comment: It’s always *den*, not *einen*, when you’re referring to buying one at the store, because only the latest issue is available there. In a waiting room, there may be multiple *Stern* issues and other magazines, so *einen* would be okay.

Answer (score -3):

Es ist vollkommen Pampe, dass eine Oberkategorie ein anderes Geschlecht hat. Unterschiedliche Oberkategorien haben unterschiedliche Geschlechter - das vererbt sich aber nicht auf Unterkategorien. Nie.

Es gibt auch keine ausgezeichneten Oberkategorien die irgendwelche Vorfahrtsrechte hätten. Die Zeitschrift - das Magazin - das Druckwerk - das Verlagsprodukt - die Veröffentlichung - das Medium - der Nachrichtenträger: welche Kategorie soll denn gemeint sein?

Der Wagen, das Fahrzeug, die Limousine, der PKW, das Gefährt, das Automobil, das Auto, die Droschke...

Noch allgemeiner: Die Sache, der Gegenstand, das Ding. Such Dir was aus!

Comment: Super downvotes, so ganz ohne Argument!

Comment: Ließ deinen ersten Satz, dann weißt du es...

Comment: Es war ja auch eine super Antwort, so ganz ohne Bezug zur originalen
Frage. Eigentlich war es gar keine Antwort, sondern ein dahingerotzer
Kommentar, der unter meiner Antwort hätte stehen sollen. Daß
Du die Antwort, die Du kommentierst, offensichtlich nicht verstanden
hast, kommt noch dazu (von Ober- und Unterkategorien habe ich
nirgendwo gesprochen). Aber ich bin ja ein netter Mensch und erklär's
Dir nochmal:

Comment: Es gibt einige Arten von Objekten (z.B. motorisierte Straßenfahrzeuge),
bei denen das Genus eines Eigennamens (z.B. "BMW", "Harley", "Polo"
"Wartburg") typischerweise von der Kategorie bestimmt wird, zu der
das Objekt gehört (Auto → maskulin: "der BMW", "der Polo", "der Wartburg";
Motorrad → feminin: "die BMW", "die Harley"), und zwar unabhängig
davon, welches Genus der Eigenname in einem anderen Kontext
möglicherweise hat. Ähnlich gilt das auch für Käsesorten, 
Schnäpse (maskulin), Zigaretten, Zigarren (feminin), aber
eben nicht für Zeitungen. War das jetzt verständlich genug?

Comment: @Uwe: Sub- und Oberkategorien gibt es ganz ohne Dein Zutun, das musst Du schon entschuldigen. Und wieso ist die Kategorie Auto und nicht die Subkategorie Roadster, Kombi, Limousine oder Zweisitzer? Wer bestimmt denn, welche Kategorie man im Kopf haben muss? Wie kommt man von "Das Motorrad" auf "Die Kawasaki"?