# Warum ist ‘Deutsche Grammophon’ feminin?

Tags: noun, gender, brand-name

Alle Wörterbucher, die ich finden kann, sagen, dass *Grammophon* ein neutrales Wort ist. Aber das klassische Musikunternehmen heißt *Deutsch**e** Grammophon* und der Name ist anscheinend feminin.

Wieso? War *Grammophon* früher feminin?

Comment: Loosely related: [“Bring noch eine/einen Stern mit”](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/13507/9551)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Du hast recht, dass *Deutsche Grammophon* feminin ist. Gleichzeitig ist das Grammophon [unbestritten neutral](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=Grammophon). Des Rätsels Lösung ist, dass die Deutsche Grammophon laut [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_Grammophon) 1898 als die *Deutsche Grammophon **Gesellschaft*** gegründet wurde – *die* Gesellschaft ist feminin.

Später (1900) wurde die Gesellschaft zu einer Aktiengesellschaft umgewandelt, und demnach *Deutsche Grammophon AG* genannt; dass hierbei das Kürzel *AG* nur »mitgedacht« wird, passiert häufiger.

Da es sich heute nicht mehr um eine Gesellschaft, sondern nur noch um ein Label handelt, wäre es nicht mehr korrekt, von einer »Deutschen Grammophon-Gesellschaft« oder »-AG« zu sprechen, sie wird aber noch beim Genus des Wortes mitgedacht.